# Why is parallelism not violated here?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

**The labour union is negotiating a contract with the hospital that will satisfy the demand of the workers and be accepted to all levels of management.**

I was asked to find out a mistake in the sentence above. I thought it to be the phrase "be accepted", considering it sounds a little awkward and also not parallel to the tense of the verb "will satisfy" used previously in the sentence.
I was told the sentence has no error. Why is my explanation wrong in this case?

Comment: There's no reason that the tenses of a compound predicate must be the same.  It would be fine to say, "The labor union has negotiated a contract that **has satisfied** the demands of the workers and **will be accepted** to all levels of management."

Comment: Did someone say parallelism is not violated here?  "... will satisfy the demand of the workers and be accept**able** to all levels ..." (or "... will satisfy the demand of the workers and be accepted **by** all levels ...")

Comment: @Kris, You have correctly pointed out the mistake  with "accepted to" but surely that is not a parallelism error.

Comment: The actual original sentence from the SAT (you can find it by Googling) contained *"acceptable"* and not *"accepted"*. Is this a typo on your part or on the part of whoever gave the sentence to you? Because I think the sentence with *"be acceptable"* is fine, while the parallelism in the sentence with *"be accepted"* is slightly awkward.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Can you add further? I'm feeling interested.

Comment: I don't see in the original sentence different tenses, because it may also be understood as "*The labour union is negotiating a contract with the hospital that will 1) satisfy the demand of the workers and 2) be accepted by/at all levels of management*. 1) and 2) use the future. The only difference is that 1) uses the active form and 2 the passive.

Answer (score 4):

You are focusing on the wrong issue. The error is the use of the word "to". As Graffito commented, the contract might be accepted by all levels of management, or accepted at all levels. It might be acceptable to all levels, or acceptable at all levels. It cannot be accepted to all levels.

Answer (score 2):

The requirement of "parallelism" is that the conjunction "and" should connect phrases of the same grammatical category, and the constituent formed will be of this same category.  Auxiliary verbs are followed by verb phrases (VP), so in the example, "will" must be followed by a VP.  A VP may consist of two VPs connected by "and", so this gets us a structure "... that will [VP VP and VP ]".  The first of the conjoined VPs is "satisfy the demand of the workers", and the second VP is "be acceptable to all levels of management".  That gets us to the following grammatical structure.

> The labour union is negotiating a contract with the hospital that will [VP [VP satisfy the demand of the workers] and [VP be acceptable to all levels of management]].